# Java "unchecked call to compareTo(T) as a member of the raw type java.lang.Comparable"

Tags: java, generics, comparable, unchecked

I'm trying to implement a sorted list as a simple exercise in Java. To make it generic I have an `add(Comparable obj)` so I can use it with any class that implements the Comparable interface.

But, when I use `obj.compareTo(...)` anywhere in the code I get `"unchecked call to compareTo(T) as a member of the raw type java.lang.Comparable"` from the compiler (with `-Xlint:unchecked` option). The code works just fine but I can't figure out how to get rid of that annoying message.

Any hints?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In essence, this warning says that `Comparable` object can't be compared to arbitrary objects. `Comparable<T>` is a generic interface, where type parameter `T` specifies the type of the object this object can be compared to.

So, in order to use `Comparable<T>` correctly, you need to make your sorted list generic, to express a constraint that your list stores objects that can be compared to each other, something like this:

```
public class SortedList<T extends Comparable<? super T>> {
    public void add(T obj) { ... }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Should be `T extends Comparable<? super T>`.

Comment: Why `Comparable<? super T>` ? `Comparable<T>` seems about fine. I implemented a binary search tree with that and can compile it with no warning and it works: https://pastebin.com/Xd78bLC4 .

Answer (score 9):

Using an interface like `Comparable` as a method parameter doesn't make your class generic, declaring and using  generic type parameters is how you make it generic.

***Quick-n-dirty answer:*** You are receiving the warning because you are using `Comparable`, which is a generic interface, as a raw type, rather than giving it a specific type arguments, like `Comparable<String>`.

To fix this, make `add()` generic by specifying type parameters:

```
<T extends Comparable<? super T>> add(T obj) { ... }
```

But this quick fix won't fix the general problem that your class is unsafe. After all, shouldn't all the objects in your list be of the same type?  This `add` method lets you still different types into the same list.  What happens when you try to compare heterogeneous types (how do you `compareTo` an `Object` instance to an `Number` instance, or to a String instance)? You can depend on the user of the class to do the right thing and ensure they only stick 1 kind of thing in your list, but a generic class will let the compiler enforce this rule.

***The better approach:*** The proper fix is that your sorted list class should be probably be generic overall, just like the other collection classes in `java.util`.

You would probably like something like:

```
public class SortedList<T extends Comparable<? super T>>
implements Iterable<T> {
    ...
    public void add(T item) { ... }
    public Iterator<T> iterator() { ... }
    ...
}
```

Note that when the class is generic, the `add` method uses the classes formal type parameter rather than declaring its own formal type parameter.

There should be plenty of tutorials on the web on how to create a generic class, but here's a quick example:

http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#FAQ002

```
class Pair<X,Y>  {  
  private X first; 
  private Y second;
  public Pair(X a1, Y a2) { 
    first  = a1; 
    second = a2; 
  } 
  public X getFirst()  { return first; } 
  public Y getSecond() { return second; } 
  public void setFirst(X arg)  { first = arg; } 
  public void setSecond(Y arg) { second = arg; } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to "check" or define the Comparable object like so:

```
add(Comparable<Object> obj)
```