# Java: Why is using a Generified Function better than taking Interface Type as a Function Argument?

Tags: java

In the following code, the method `isSorted` causes my static code analyzer to give me a warning saying:

`Unchecked call to 'compareTo(T)' as a member of raw type 'java.lang.comparable'`

Now, I found from [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830400/java-unchecked-call-to-comparetot-as-a-member-of-the-raw-type-java-lang-compa) that the solution is to generify the function as done in the equivalent function `isSortedG`.

However, I do not understand why the second method is better than the first. As far as I can tell, since `isSorted` takes a `Comparable[]` as argument, this should result in a compile time check of any usage of that function to make sure that the input array is indeed of a type that implements `Comparable`.

In other words, what is this 'Unchecked call' that the static checker is warning about?

```
public class SortChecker{
    public boolean isSorted(Comparable[] arr){
        if(arr.length == 1){
            return true;
        }
        for(int i = 1; i < arr.length; ++i){
            if(arr[i].compareTo(arr[i-1]) < 0){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public <T extends Comparable<? super T>> boolean isSortedG(T[] arr){
        if(arr.length == 1){
            return true;
        }
        for(int i = 1; i < arr.length; ++i){
            if(arr[i].compareTo(arr[i-1]) < 0){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nongeneric `Comparable` "can" be compared to any `Object` (as per its `compareTo()` signature), but in actuality, there may only be a small set of types to which it can be meaningfully compared (and giving it other types will cause `compareTo()` to throw an exception). For example, you can cast an `Integer` to a `Comparable`, but that still won't let you compare it to a `String`. Therefore, a `Comparable[]` is risky business, because you have no idea which elements are safe to compare and which are not. The generic version is safer because a `Comparable<T>` usually is comparable to any `T`, and if `T` is constrained to implementors of `Comparable<? super T>`, all elements of a `T[]` should be mutually comparable.